# Why 256 for a signed char is undefined in C++

Tags: c++, char, signed

Reading the C++ Primer 5th edition book, I noticed that a `signed char` with a value of `256` is undefined.
I decided to try that, and I saw that `std::cout` didn't work for that char variable. (Printed Nothing).

But on C, the same thing
`signed char c = 256;`
would give a value `0` for the `char c`.

I tried searching but didn't find anything.

Can someone explain to me why is this the case in C++?

Edit: I understand that 256 is 2 bytes, but why doesn't the same thing as in C, happen to C++?

Comment: The largest value is 255, 256 values from 0 to 255.

Comment: I know that, the same is in C right? 255 is still the largest value. But why doesn't the same thing with C happen to C++?

Comment: They are different languages, C and C++, and hence have different conventions.

Comment: @CodingMash, I believe C++ has C as a subset. At least that's what most books state.

Comment: BTW it prints nullbyte, not nothing

Comment: C++ contains C as a subset, and also inherits many features but their standards are different.

Comment: @RiaD nothing visible. that's what I meant.

Comment: No, C++ does not contain C as a subset, only nearly so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: See T.C.'s answer below. It's better.

Signed integer overflow is undefined in C++ and C. In most implementations, the maximum value of `signed char`, `SCHAR_MAX`, is 127 and so putting 256 into it will overflow it. Most of the time you will see the number simply wrap around (to 0), but this is still undefined behavior.

Comment: So the overflow is not standard behavior?

Comment: @cprogcr No, not at all. `unsigned` numbers are guaranteed to wrap around though.

Comment: Ahh OK. In C I would always get that overflow, and I'm pretty new to C++. Thanks

Comment: @cprogcr Again, it is undefined behavior in C too. Compiler optimizations can take advantage of it and transform expressions like `(x < x + 1)` into `true`, even though this wouldn't be true if signed numbers wrapped around.

Answer (score 10):

The book is wildly incorrect. There's no undefined behavior in

```
signed char c = 256;
```

`256` is an integer literal of type `int`. To initialize a `signed char` with it, it is converted to `signed char` (§8.5 [dcl.init]/17.8; all references are to N4140). This conversion is governed by §4.7 [conv.integral]:

> 1 A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of
>   another integer type. A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type can be
>   converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
>
> 2  If the destination type is unsigned,  [...]
>
> 3  If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can
>   be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width);
>   **otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.**

If `signed char` cannot represent 256, then conversion yields an implementation-defined value of type `signed char`, which is then used to initialize `c`. There is nothing undefined here.

---

When people say "signed overflow is UB", they are usually referring to the rule in §5 [expr]/p4:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not
>   mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for
>   its type, the behavior is undefined.

This renders UB expressions like `INT_MAX + 1` - the operands are both `int`s, so the result's type is also `int`, but the value is outside the range of representable values. This rule does not apply here, as the only expression is `256`, whose type is `int`, and 256 is obviously in the range of representable values for `int`.

Comment: *"This renders UB expressions like `INT_MAX + 1`"* This doesn't seem to apply to constant expressions, while `int i = INT_MAX + 1;` is UB, making `i` constant `const int i = INT_MAX + 1;` will invoke an implicit conversion (whatever type `INT_MAX + 1` can fit into, to `int`), which is implementation defined. One thing I'm not sure about, though, how can signed chars and short ints ever produce integer overflow (assuming char < short < int)? Since doing any arithmetic with them will always involve the usual arithmetic conversions, which will always lead to an implementation defined conversion.

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing the difference between `cout` and `printf`. When you output a character with `cout` you don't get the numeric representation, you get a single character. In this case the character was `NUL` which doesn't appear on-screen.

See the example at http://ideone.com/7n6Lqc

Answer (score 2):

A char is generally `8 bits` or a `byte`, therefore can hold `2^8` different values. If it is `unsigned`, from `0` to `255` otherwise, when `signed` from `-128` to `127`

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned char` values is (to be pedantic, usually) is from 0 to 255. There is 256 values, that 1 byte may hold.

If you get overflow (usually) values are used modulo 256, as other Integer type modulo `MAX + 1`