# Storing hexadecimal number in char

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  char  a = 0xAA;
  int b;

  b = (int)a;
  b = b >> 4;

  printf("%x\n", b);
  return 0;
}
```

Here the output is `fffffffa`. Could anyone please explain to me how this output was obtained?

Comment: Probably a signed char, this may help `unsigned char a=0xAA;`

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as a "hexadecimal number".  Rather you may have a "hexadecimal representation of a number", just as you may have a decimal or binary representation of the same number.  A number is a number -- it has no base.

Comment: @HotLicks Heh... Of course you could follow that up with "there's no such thing as a number" - "numbers" are just mental constructs that humans have come up with to assist in thinking logically about stuff, if there is indeed such a thing as "logic"... ;-P

Comment: @twalberg - I'm not sure I see the logic of that. ;-P

Answer (score 3):

C standard allows compiler designers choose if `char` is signed or unsigned. It appears that your system uses signed `char`s and 32-bit `int`s. Since the most significant bit of `0xAA` (binary `10101010`) is set, the value gets sign-extended into `0xFFFFFFAA`.

Shifting signed values right also sign-extends the result, so when you shift out the lower four bits, four ones get shifted in from the left, resulting in the final output of `0xFFFFFFFA`.

**EDIT :** According to C99 specification, hexadecimal integer constants such as `0xAA` in your example are treated as `int`s of different length depending on their length. Therefore, assigning `0xAA` to a signed `char` is out of range: a proper way of assigning the value would be with a hexadecimal character literal, like this:

```
char a='\xAA';
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not signed overflow?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569566/why-256-for-a-signed-char-is-undefined-in-c

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I'm pretty sure that a right-shift will never cause an overflow - that's a sign-extension scenario. A left-shift, though, could easily cause overflow...

Comment: Well if it is a signed char he is assigning an out of range value to `a` which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Good question! `0xAA` is an `int`, not `char`. If he used `'\xAA'`, I would be sure that it's not a `char` overflow; I'd need to check the standard to say for sure.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Oh, *that* overflow... (Guess I should have checked the link). Yeah, that's probably undefined from the standpoint of the standard. But most implementations probably would consider `char a=0xaa` equivalent to `char a=-86`...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like 0xAA got sign extended when you put it into an int to 0xFFFFFFAA.  Then, when you right-shifted it by four bits (one hex character) you ended up with 0xFFFFFFFA.

```
  //a is 8-bits wide.  If you interpret this as a signed value, it's negative
  char a=0xAA;

  int b; //b is 32 bits wide here, also signed

  //the compiler sign-extends A to 0xFFFFFFAA to keep the value negative
  b=(int)a; 

  b=b>>4; //right-shift maintains the sign-bit, so now you have 0xFFFFFFFA
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard allows `char` to be either `signed` or `unsigned` in your case it looks like it is `signed`. Assigning `0xAA` to a `signed char` is [signed overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569566/why-256-for-a-signed-char-is-undefined-in-c) and therefore undefined behavior. So if you change your declaration to this:

```
unsigned char a=0xAA;
```

you should get the results you expect.