# What guarantees that a static_cast of a UTF-8 code unit stored in a char32_t or char16_t to char will turn out as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

When using the C++11 standard, is there any guarantee that an ASCII character stored in a `char32_t` or `char16_t` codepoint will be properly cast to `char`?

`char32_t` and `char16_t` are both defined to always be unsigned (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). However, `char` may be signed or unsigned depending on the system.

I would assume that ASCII characters always work:

```
char32_t original = U'b';
char value = static_cast<char>(original);
```

However, what about values that are `UTF-8` code units, which start with the first bit == 1, and are extracted from the `UTF-32` character using a bitmask during conversion, e.g.:

```
char32_t someUtf32CodeUnit = 0x00001EA9;
// Third code-unit of ẩ
char extractedCodeUnit = static_cast<char>(((someUtf32CodeUnit >> 6) & 0x3F) | 0x80);
```

Is it guaranteed that the conversion on all systems will work the same way (resulting in the same expected bits of said `UTF-8` code unit) or will the unsigned<->signed casts potentially make any difference?

Comment: `'b'` is not ASCII encoded. You need to say `char32_t c = U'b'`. In C++17 you can say `char c = u8'b'` to get a UTF-8 value of type `char`, which is the same as ASCII for the first 128 values.

Comment: @KerrekSB thanks, fixed

Comment: AFAIK signed-unsigned casts are purely a matter of syntax, that is, for human consumption; the bits are always simply re-interpreted, without any conversion of any sort. So, unless you find a machine which is not using two's complement, you should not expect any problems.  Of course, I know this is answering your question, because you are asking if there is any *guarantee*.  Good question!

Comment: Nothing guarantees your expectations, but if they're in line with the language specification, the language specification guarantees it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

as far as I know, C++ (including C++11) is agnostic about the coding used for the `char` type. The only requirement (§3.9.1.1) is that a `char` must be able to store any character of the basic character set defined in §2.3. Therefore even ASCII characters outside the set, like `@` or `` ` ``,  are not guaranteed to be stored in a `char`. Their code point values could obviously be stored, but the machine might interpret them  as different glyphs (for functions like `isalpha` and similars)

Even if you are just interested in storing the values, in your example you try to `static_cast` an `int` expression  to a `char`. In case your `char` is a signed type and value is bigger than 127, the result is implementation-defined, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28453985) for details.