# Overflow char to int conversion

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int a);

int main() {
    char ch = 256;
    func(ch);
    return 0;
}

void func(int a) {
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

The output of the above program is `0`.
Can anyone explain how

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings, they would tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @PSkocik Lossy conversion is not undefined behavior. Only non-conversion signed overflow is. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28453985/3425536).

Comment: Lossy conversion for signed types: "either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`256` is too large for the `char` type on your machine.

So it wraps around to the minimum value `0`, as per the C standard (from N1570, emphasis mine):

> #### 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value
>   can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> 2 Otherwise, if
>   the new type is unsigned, **the value is converted by repeatedly adding
>   or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented
>   in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.**<sup>60)</sup>
>
> 3
>   Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
>   in it; either **the result is implementation-defined** or an
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.

The `256` literal is an `int`, and `char` is an integer type that is either signed or unsigned, so one of the above emphasized behaviors will occur.

Comment: Good answer. The maximum value for char cannot be determined from the code OP posted though.

Comment: @2501 True. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Because Character set is limited to 255 characters only so your output is 0

http://www.asciitable.com/ have complete list of characterset details and char is limited to 256 only
unsigned char   1 byte  -> 0 to 255
signed char     1 byte  -> -128 to 127

Comment: That's actually 256 characters in total.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to store 256 in 8 bits...it gets all the 1[00000000]. So basically it overflows and the 0 bits are only left.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void func(int a);

int main() {
    char ch = 256;
    printf("%c\n",ch); //nothing prints. That's what happens when
                       // when we print 'NUL'
    func(ch);
    return 0;
}

void func(int a) {
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

Comment: bits not bytes.

Comment: @Till.: Trying to be fast... :D

Answer (score 0):

The maximum range of `char` is `127`. The value `256` is `129` more than `127` and when we add `1` to `127` (which is maximum value of char) it goes to minimum value `-128`. So if we add `129` to `127` it results in `0`.

for char 
127 + 1 = -128.
127 + 129 = 0

So for the below program the output is 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int a);

int main() {
    char ch = 257;
    func(ch);
    return 0;
}

void func(int a) {
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

Comment: You do understand that signed whole numbers are stored as 2's compliment right?

Comment: `char` may be `signed` or `unsigned`; the value stored in `ch` is implementation-defined behavior if `ch` is a `signed` integer type.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile this with gcc it actually tells you why:

```
testo.c: In function ‘main’:
testo.c:6:15: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
     char ch = 256;
               ^
```